# printing first row of CSV file as a dictionary format, sorted by keys

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python 3 and my goal is to read a .csv file and print it's just first row into dictionary(json) format ,that too in sort by keys.I put enough effort and need help. All I tried is as below:-

```
def list_of_csvs(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, mode = 'r') as csvFile:
       reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
       for row in reader:
           return row 


row = list_of_csvs('NYC-CitiBike-2016.csv')
print(dict(row))
```

though it's still not sorted by key. Please suggest the best way to do it.

output should look as below (see sorted key and alignment)

```
City: NYC
{'bikeid': '17109',
 'birth year': '',
 'end station id': '401',
 'end station latitude': '40.72019576',
 'end station longitude': '-73.98997825',
 'end station name': 'Allen St & Rivington St',
 'gender': '0',
 'start station id': '532',
 'start station latitude': '40.710451',
 'start station longitude': '-73.960876',
 'start station name': 'S 5 Pl & S 4 St',
 'starttime': '1/1/2016 00:09:55',
 'stoptime': '1/1/2016 00:23:54',
 'tripduration': '839',
 'usertype': 'Customer'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort the dict, try something like this:

```
print({k: mydict[k] for k in sorted(mydict)})
```

Comment: P.S. Different formatting options from the standard library include json.dumps() and pprint().

Comment: Thanks @Shaheed Haque, It's working as expected now. May you please also suggest, how can I write it in better manner, any suggestion?. What if I use csv.reader?. Is above mentioned code good enough, as I wrote it through hits and trails?